# C - String concatenation

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I am trying to take in two unsigned integers like:

```
 int swap(unsigned char first, unsigned char second){


 }
```

These unsigned char's are going to be numbers such as '2' or '0'.

The goal I am trying to achieve is to make a character 'string' with these two unsigned chars concatenated and to add another zero on the end.

```
     printf("\n%u\n", first);
     printf("%u\n", second);
     unsigned char zero = "0";
     printf("%u\n", zero); 

     char *string;
     char zero = 0;
     strcat(string, first);
     strcat(string, second);
     strcat(string, zero);
     printf("String: %s", string);
```

In this case if first is '0' and second is '2', I want the output string to be '020' so that i can convert this from hex to an integer. I saw online I can do this from it being in this char 'string' form.

Comment: I don't understand what the `swap()` function has to do with an implementation of `parse_hex()` function... Nor do I understand how any of the code shown has anything to do with either of those things.

Comment: First it's unsigned integers, then unsigned chars, then swap, then hexadecimals... You lost me a loooong time ago...

Answer (score 1):

Too much work.

```
char result[4];
result[0] = first;
result[1] = second;
result[2] = '0';
result[3] = '\0';
```

Comment: How can I print the entire result in one print statement? This worked fine thank you

Comment: By printing `result`. It's a string.

Comment: char result[4];
 result[0] = first;
 result[1] = second;
 result[2] = '0';
 result[3] = '\0';
 printf("Result: %s", result);

The result gets printed as nothing.

Comment: Then `first` and `second` aren't what you think they are.

Comment: they are unsigned chars. those lines I put in the comments above are the first command executed in a function that takes in two unsigned chars as parameters

Comment: So then are they '2' and '0', or are they 2 and 0?

Answer (score 0):

I think before you parse the variables first and second into your function, you should first convert them into char. So one way to do this, is to use sprintf() first, before extracting first and second. So it's something like:

```
int urNumber = 20; //example
int Length;
char *buffer;

Length = sprintf(buffer, "%d", urNumber);
if(Length == 2)
{
swap(buffer[0], buffer[1]);
}
```